# Facebook: get list of users that has granted permission to use the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to get a list of users that has granted permission for the app to get their details?

so far all i know is how to check one user if he has granted permission for your app using this code

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response2) {
});
```

but what if you want to get the names of all the users who has given your app the permission to get their details?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `application` object has the connection `subscriptions`, which lists the users, pages, and  permissions. You can also use `app` instead of the ID, because it will be associated through your access token.

```
FB.api('/app/subscriptions', function(response2) {
});
```

See [the application api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) for details.